# C# read a matrix from console (for example copy/paste from a textfile)

Tags: c#, string, matrix, console

I am wondering which is the best practice to read a matrix entered directly to the console as string with copy/paste from a text file?

This is an example of the matrix, however as a whole sting with the new lines at the end and without newlines between the rows (I do not know how to represent a matrix here, sorry):

*5 6 8 12 34*

13 4 9 20 3

8 17 2 2 5

It would be great to have a int[,] as a result which would be able to be written on the console with something like nested loops.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the novice question (may be)!

Comment: Look at [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you cant do new lines without writing an replacement, however you could do a prefix, something like 3x3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 as a 3 by 3 matrix

Comment: So you want to read one line or multiple, if so what should be the last line? (a dot `.`, empty line...)? And do you want to dynamically figure out the dimensions? And lastly, what are the numbers - always `int` ?

Comment: I would like to read the whole matrix, ending with entering a new line at the end. And it would be great to dynamically figure out the dims. And yes, the numbers are always `int`.
@HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I couldn't quite get your point. What do you mean by prefix? To initially have a 3x3 matrix or?

Comment: the idea was to give the dimension to the array of numbers, buy you want it to figure it out dynamically, the problem is, that you cant get the newline, either you hae to do what rbm writes and replace the new line with a readable char. May i ask why how do you except to execute the program, is it with another program or ?

Comment: I am just trying to find a way how to enter a matrix in the console with copy/paste from a .doc file. It is probably better to use System.IO class and to use a method to read it from the file, but I am just wondering how this could be done without reading the file internally in the program.
I intend to use this code to read a matrix and then to manipulate it in different ways, e.g. finding the max value for a sub matrix with diff dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) =>
            {//prevent from stopping after Ctrl+C
                e.Cancel = true;
            };

        Console.WriteLine("\n Enter a matrix. Press Ctrl+C when you will have ended.");


        string text = Console.In.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("\nParsing...\n");
        int[,] res2a;
        try
        {              
            res2a = parse(text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ",\n " + ex.StackTrace);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nYou enter: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < res2a.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < res2a.GetLength(0); j++)
                Console.Write("0x{0:X} ", res2a[j, i]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    static int[,] parse(string text)
    { 
        int max_len = 0;
        List<List<int>> res2x = new List<List<int>>();
        string [] tmp1 = text.Split(new char []{'\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(string s1 in tmp1)
        {
            string [] tmp2 = s1.Split(new char [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            res2x.Add(new List<int>(tmp2.ToList().ConvertAll<int>((s)=>int.Parse(s.Trim()))));
            if (tmp2.Length > max_len)
                max_len = tmp2.Length;
        }

        int[,] res2a = new int[max_len, tmp1.Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp1.Length; j++ )
            for (int i = 0; i < res2x[j].Count; i++)                
                res2a[i, j] = res2x[j][i];
        return res2a;
    }
}
```

It looks something ugly, but I don't have a time at now. Maybe, I can to improve this later.